# Not able to render the html code in browser using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

When I try to add the  tag in angular JS and render, it doesn't display the image, but rather it displays the img code as it is.
Here is my Angular JS code

```
$scope.option = '<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">';
    responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        for(index in data) {
            $scope.usersArray.push({
                name:data[index].name,
                password:data[index].password,
                option:$scope.option
            });
        }           
    });
```

### My html code

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in usersArray">
   <td><span ng-model="user.name">{{user.name}}</span></td>
   <td><span ng-model="user.password">{{user.password}}</span></td>
   <td><span ng-model="user.option">{{user.option}}</td>
</tr>
```

Other details are coming fine, except the tag. Do I need to add anything extra here?

Comment: [ngBindHtml](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't deal withn HTML in the controller, but with structured data. You should generate the HTML in the view:

controller:

```
$scope.option = {
    src: 'smiley.png',
    alt: 'Smiley face',
    width: 42,
    height: 42
};
responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    for(index in data) {
        $scope.usersArray.push({
            name:data[index].name,
            password:data[index].password,
            option: $scope.option
        });
    }           
});
```

view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in usersArray">
   <td><span ng-model="user.name">{{user.name}}</span></td>
   <td><span ng-model="user.password">{{user.password}}</span></td>
   <td><span ng-model="user.option">
       <img ng-src="{{ user.option.src }}" alt="{{ user.option.alt }} width="{{user.option.width}}" height="{{user.option.height }}" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. Worked like a charm. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the directive bindHTML.

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="ngBindHtmlCtrl">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('ngBindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize']).controller('ngBindHtmlCtrl', ['$scope', function ngBindHtmlCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML =
     'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with <a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
}]);
```

Doc: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$scope.option =  $sce.trustAsHtml('<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">');
```

You need to inject `$sce`.

What is $sce?

$sce is a service that provides Strict Contextual Escaping services to AngularJS. Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) is a mode in which AngularJS requires bindings in certain contexts to result in a value that is marked as safe to use for that context.

Refer : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: What is $sce? I didn't use it anywhere else?

Comment: Just to tell Angular that it is safe to use the html content that you are trying to include.